# CSS different vertical-align of elements next to each other (top, middle, top)

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Assume I have DIV and inside 3 columns. Col1 and Col3 have random height, but Col2 is always 20px height. What I need, is to get Col2 to be always in the middle. Unfortunately when I set vertical-align for the columns like: top, middle, top - it doesn't seem to work properly. Col2 is rendered on top (or rather couple of pixels below) despite it set to middle.

When I set all 3 columns vertical-align to middle - Col2 magically is rendered in the middle. But I really don't want Col1 and Col3 to be in middle.

When I set them like: top, middle, middle - Col2 works fine, too. And it looks OK when Col3 is the highest. But I cannot guarantee height of Col1 or Col3, so this solution also bad.

Tested in FF26, IE9, Opera12.

Why is that happening? Am I doing something wrong here?

My code:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        background: gray;
    }
    .col1 {
        width: 20px;
        height: 60px;
        background: red;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .col2 {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: yellow;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .col3 {
        width: 20px;
        height: 80px;
        background: cyan;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col1">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `vertical-align` uses `line-height` of the parent element for reference, so what you're looking for probably won't work with `vertical-align`, unless you set the parent's `line-height` to the same as the tallest column's `height`. (For testing, just insert `line-height: 80px;` into the `.container` rule.)

Comment: Why is it working when all columns are set to ``middle`` then?

Comment: Because they *all* use the parent element's `line-height`, then, and the parent element just pads top and bottom so everything fits in. (That's why inline images cause spacing between lines. ;) )

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Still, shouldn't ``line-height`` fit the highest element in the line?

Comment: Nope. `line-height` is [by default](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) set to `normal`, which has a recommended value between `1.0` and `1.2` multiplied with `font-size`.

Comment: That explains a lot. Many thanks for your help. (Funny thing is, that after I manage to solve the issue with ``display: table-cell`` it actually don't look so good as I though it would be. :) Still, it's good to learn something new.)